# How do I get Rails 4.1.1 to write to the log file in Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Log output is going to the console, but I want it to go to the log file also. Windows console is not so good for keeping track of separate requests. If I delete the file, it will create `log/development.log`, but it doesn't write to it except for one line! ("Logfile created on...")

Here is my config/environment/development.rb (I've tried several combinations of commenting/uncommenting)

```
  config.log_level = :debug
  # Rails.logger = Logger.new("log/development.log")
  config.logger = Logger.new("log/development.log")
```

Here is my environment

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\Tyger>rails runner 'puts Rails.env'
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Vanity: loading experiments from C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/Tyger/experiments
Vanity: loading metrics from C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/Tyger/experiments/metrics
development
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

Comment: Are you sure you're running in development environment?